Why I can't connect google functions to Mysql?
I created a google function to connect to Mysql, I created the database using Cloud SQL. I gave it Cloud permissions.
Here's the code inside my 1st gen function (main.py). Please keep in mind "" actually have my keys
import os

from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector, IPTypes
import pymysql
import sqlalchemy
def connect_with_connector() -> sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
    """
    Initializes a connection pool for a Cloud SQL instance of MySQL.

    Uses the Cloud SQL Python Connector package.
    """


    instance_connection_name = os.environ[
        ""
    ]  # 'project:region:instance'
    db_user = os.environ[""]  #  'my-db-user'
    db_pass = os.environ[""]  #  'my-db-password'
    db_name = os.environ[""]  #  'my-database'

    ip_type = IPTypes.PRIVATE if os.environ.get("PRIVATE_IP") else IPTypes.PUBLIC

    connector = Connector(ip_type)

    def getconn() -> pymysql.connections.Connection:
        conn: pymysql.connections.Connection = connector.connect(
            instance_connection_name,
            "pymysql",
            user=db_user,
            password=db_pass,
            db=db_name,
        )
        return conn

    pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        "mysql+pymysql://",
        creator=getconn,
        # ...
    )
    return pool


As entry point I have 'connect_with_connector'
On requierements.txt I have
google-cloud-sql-connector
pymysql
sqlalchemy

I followed this documentation
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions
There's not important information on logs.

If you're getting an error, or unexpected results, please show them.

I got the following Build failed: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-cloud-sql-connector (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for google-cloud-sql-connector; Error ID: 656dd225

google-cloud-sql-connector is not the correct package name.

cloud-sql-python-connector[pymysql] Try that instead.

Now I got No module named 'cloud_sql_python_connector

Did you include [pymysql] in the package name?

Yeah, still not working

Wait -- is this latest error happening in the python code, or in the pip install command?

Once I create the function I get the message Build failed: ERROR google-cloud-sql-connector is not the correct package name

Yes, I already pointed out that is not the correct package name.  I am confused.

Have you tried pip install "cloud-sql-python-connector[pg8000]" ?

Did you add a serverless VPC connector to your function?

@snakecharmerb, Thank you for pointing out that. I made a mistake, it was supposed to be pip install "cloud-sql-python-connector[pymysql]".
